# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory cv2

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, computer-vision

When I am trying to migrate file to Heroku master (deploying to Heroku)

These errors comes:

```
    (test) C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\django-project\imageapi>heroku run python manage.py migrate
           Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ imageapii... up, run.9341 (Free)
           Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/app/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
     main()
  File "/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 591, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/app/imageapi/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from core.views import TextView,fetching
  File "/app/core/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    import cv2 as cv
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and my pip list :

```
Package             Version
------------------- ---------
asgiref             3.4.1
certifi             2021.5.30
chardet             4.0.0
dj-database-url     0.5.0
Django              3.2.5
django-cors-headers 3.7.0
django-heroku       0.3.1
djangorestframework 3.12.4
gunicorn            20.1.0
idna                2.10
numpy               1.21.0
opencv-python       4.5.2.54
Pillow              8.3.0
pip                 21.1.3
psycopg2            2.9.1
pytz                2021.1
PyYAML              5.4.1
requests            2.25.1
setuptools          57.0.0
sqlparse            0.4.1
uritemplate         3.0.1
urllib3             1.26.6
wheel               0.36.2
whitenoise          5.2.0
```

I am doing this on window 10 and not using Docker.I tried many answer regarding this error but none of them was useful.

pls help me :(

Thanks in advance